# why does my wpf custom component listbox fire twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, expander

This class (below) is a custom component. its supposed to just search through the folders by clicking on the list inside the expander.

ExpanderList is the list in the expander

DirMaker is the actuall expander

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace BigHand
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for DirMakerControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class DirMakerControl : UserControl
{
    string currentDirectory = "c:/";        
    DirectoryInfo di;
    bool directoryEmpty;

    public DirMakerControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        getFolders();
        updateHeader();
    }

    private void getFolders()
    {
        ExpanderList.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            di = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);

            foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                ExpanderList.Items.Add(d.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            //goBack() keeps display the same
            goBack();
            MessageBox.Show("                 SORRY!!!! \nYou dont have the correct \npermisions to use these files.");
        }

        if (ExpanderList.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            directoryEmpty = true;
            ExpanderList.IsEnabled = false;
            ExpanderList.Items.Add("No Folders Here");
        }
        else
        {
            directoryEmpty = false;
            ExpanderList.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        updateHeader();
    }

    private void ListClicked(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing  
        if (ExpanderList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {

            //update list and variables
            if (!directoryEmpty)
            {
                ExpanderList.IsEnabled = true;
                currentDirectory = currentDirectory + ExpanderList.SelectedItem + "/";

                // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)  
                ExpanderList.SelectedIndex = -1;

                getFolders();
            }
        }

    }

    private void goBack()
    {
        currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Substring(0, getCurrentFolderStringIndex());

        getFolders();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        goBack();
    }

    //returns an integer representing where the current folder name starts in the current folder string
    public int getCurrentFolderStringIndex()
    {
        char[] currentD = currentDirectory.ToCharArray();

        for (int index = currentD.Length - 2; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (currentD[index] == '/')
            {
                return index + 1;                    
            }
        }

        //if this gets called(should at least start back at the c:/)
        return 0;

    }

    private void updateHeader()
    {
        //Change Header
        //get temp int to save calling the method twice
        int index = getCurrentFolderStringIndex();

        if (index == 0)            
            DirMaker.Header = currentDirectory;            
        else
        DirMaker.Header = currentDirectory.Substring(index, currentDirectory.Length - index);
    }

    private void selectionMade(ListBox sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing  
        if (ExpanderList.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        //update list and variables
        if (!directoryEmpty)
        {
            ExpanderList.IsEnabled = true;
            currentDirectory = currentDirectory + ExpanderList.SelectedItem + "/";

            // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)  
            ExpanderList.SelectedIndex = -1;

            getFolders();
        }          

    }

}
}
```

It works really well, lol apart from the private void ListClicked(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 which sometimes fires more then once which has the effect of skipping through to deeper files then one level as intended. This behaviour doesn't seem to repeat when i place a breakpoint though on the if
 (ExpanderList.SelectedIndex != -1)  line which always returns -1 and prevents this if its not supposed to happen. I have seen evidence to suggest there is a bug with this method?, although i do not have the experience or front to accuse someone else..... its definitely me although this option has been playing on my mind more as i can not find a reason for it to be repeatedly firing.

really crucial i get to the bottom of this asap its driving me crazy

Thank you in advance for any help

john harris

Comment: I know the bottom method selectionMade wouldnt work was not called at all at the point of writing this and has since been removed completly

Answer (score 0):

Playing directly with the *ListBox.Items* property is not a good idea: you should first run your retrieval of folders in a **temporary collection**, a simple List<string>, and once done you update the ListBox **in bulk**:

```
ExpanderList.Items.Clear();
foreach (string s in tmp)
{
    ExpanderList.Items.Add(s);
}
```

At least this will be more optimal, but check if that solve your issue too. :)

Comment: thank you for your time doesnt that do exactly the same as: foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                ExpanderList.Items.Add(d.ToString());
            }

Comment: Don't know why but I though your scan was recursive. :( So you could use the same idea but with a binding: you just swap the collection with the latest when you update so that there is only one refresh.